# Undefined Method 'posts_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm creating a rails app where users will be able to create posts. Unfortunately, something is going wrong with the views. Post index works, but when I try to make a new post, I get the error "undefined method `posts_path' for `#<#<Class:0x007fddd6657258>:0x007fddd39f6d58>"` The weird thing is that it references line 1 of my form view which is as follows:

```
= form_for @post, html: { class: "form form-horizontal post" } do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.label :content, class: 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control', required: true
    = error_span(@post[:content])
  = f.submit nil,class: 'btn btn-primary'
  = link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")), user_posts_path, :class => 'btn btn-default'
```

It is called from my new view which is here:

```
- model_class = Post
.page-header
  %h1=t '.title', :default => [:'helpers.titles.new', 'New %{model}'], :model => model_class.model_name.human.titleize
= render :partial => "form"
```

I cannot find any instance of 'posts_path' in my code, which is why I'm confused. My routes are properly defined here:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "users#index"
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 
`= form_for [@user, @post], html: { class: "form form-horizontal post" } do |f|` 
since your `post` routes are nested under `user`

Comment: I believe this was part of the problem, but I'm still getting the same error on that line when corrected.

Comment: Are you sure `@user` is not nil and is defined in the `new` action?

Comment: Ah! You are correct, `@user` is nil. Do I define `@user` in the `new` action of the posts controller? Just like in the user controller with a `User.find`?